# Can I add any kinda condition to the model.py file in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I add any kinda condition to this model?
If it's possible, how can I do that?

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", null=False,
                            db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} ({self.rating})"
```

Comment: *What* condition?

Comment: Some conditions can be expressed with Django's constraint framework, but not all. The main condition is that it spans over a single table.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/